# executing a popup from another popup button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, popupwindow

I am new in IOS. When I'm clicking on the following Login Button:

[image]

I'm using this code to generate a popup:

```
- (UIView *)createLoginView
{
    UIView *alertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 130)];

    UITextField *email = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 50)];
    email.tag=420;
    email.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [email setTag:99];
    [email setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [email setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    [email setPlaceholder:@"Email"];
    [email setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0 green:243/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [email setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    [email setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

    UITextField *pass = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 280, 50)];
    pass.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [pass setTag:100];
    [pass setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [pass setSecureTextEntry:YES];
    [pass setPlaceholder:@"Password"];
    [pass setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0 green:243/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [pass setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];

    [alertView addSubview:email];
    [alertView addSubview:pass];
    return alertView;
}
```

[image]

The login popup is working properly but when I click on the 'Forget?' button of the popup,  the forgot password popup does not show up. Here is the code for forget password popup.

```
- (UIView *)createForgotPasswordView
{
    UIView *alertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 130)];

    UITextField *email = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 50)];

    email.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [email setTag:22];
    [email setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [email setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    [email setPlaceholder:@"Email"];
    [email setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0 green:243/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [email setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    [email setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

    [alertView addSubview:email];
    return alertView;
}
```

And I'm using it like :

```
- (IBAction)LogInClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    IOS7AlertView *applyMsg = [[IOS7AlertView alloc] init];
    [applyMsg setContainerView:[self createLoginView]];

    [applyMsg setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Forgot?", @"Login", nil]];


    [applyMsg setOnButtonTouchUpInside:^(IOS7AlertView *alertView, int buttonIndex) {

        if(buttonIndex==0)
        {

            [alertView close];

            NSLog(@"Forgot Section");

            IOS7AlertView *applyPop = [[IOS7AlertView alloc] init];
            [applyPop setParentView:[self createForgotPasswordView]];


            [applyPop setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Next", @"Cancel", nil]];

        }
}];
```

But the problem is the next popup does not show up? What is the problem? Please help.

Comment: Please be aware that as of iOS 7 you should no longer add subViews to `UIAlertView`. From the documentation: The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Comment: @rckoenes I do have to say where is the `UIAlertView` I'd be more concerned with the code behind `IOS7AlertView` in case they are subclassing `UIAlertView`. I can't actually see the purpose of this code though since they aren't doing anything that `UIAlertView` already does for them.

Comment: @Popeye you are completely right, there is no need to add the `UITextField` yourself. My comment was more pointed to the part of the documentation where it is stated the de view hierarchy is private. Thus inserting your own view could mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

already `UIalertview` hierarchy has email and password options.

try this and this is native

```
 - (IBAction)LogInClick:(UIButton *)sender {
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Login"
                      message:nil
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Signup"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Login",@"Forgot password", nil];

 alert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0]setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0]setPlaceholder:@"Email address"];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:1]setPlaceholder:@"Password"];
alert.tag=10;
[alert show]; 
 }
```

and the `alert view delegate` method is

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

  if (alertView.tag==65)
  {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Login"
                      message:nil
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Signup"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Login",@"Forgot password", nil];

alert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0]setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0]setPlaceholder:@"Email address"];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:1]setPlaceholder:@"Password"];
alert.tag=10;
[alert show]; 
 }


if (alertView.tag==10)
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        NSLog(@"signup");
        //Navigate to Signup page



    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Forgot password");

       //  //Navigate to Forgot password page
     }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        NSLog(@"YES");

        NSString *usernameInput=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

        NSString *passwordInput=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;

        //pass the email id , password

        NSLog(@"1 %@", usernameInput);
        NSLog(@"2 %@", passwordInput);

        NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];


        // COMMENT: check if input information is valid or not
        if([usernameInput isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!!!" message:@"You must fill in Email address" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            alert.tag=65;
            [alert show];


        }
        else if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:usernameInput] == NO)
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!!" message:@"Please Enter Valid Email Address." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            alert.tag=65;
            [alert show];

        }
        else if([passwordInput isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!!!" message:@"You must fill in Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            alert.tag=65;
            [alert show];


        }
        else
        {
            //pass teh data to server or login process
           }

    }
      }
```

Comment: this the simple way and don't forget to assign <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> in your header file

Comment: @Anbu.Kartik : Actually my login popup is working, but the forget password popup which comes after clicking on the 'foget?' button of the login popup is not coming.

Comment: oh if u r click the forget button the popup does not appear, correct

Comment: just hide this one  [alertView close]; and try

Comment: if it is not work have give the link where u downloaded the IOS7AlertView , here i try and give the answer for u

Comment: I already tried it previously. but the problem is, use this([alertView close];) or not the login popup disappears and forget password popup does not come up

Comment: k give the link where u downloaded the IOS7AlertView , here i try and give the answer for u

Comment: I don't remember it properly but may be this link: http://gibbon.co/psy2k/ios-programming-for-beginners/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window
...though I modified the code.

Comment: give a some time i cheek and tell to u